# Can a parent and child record both be inserted in single DML statement?

Tags: dml

I have a requirement to insert both a parent and a child record, in a single DML statement. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you need to make one field as External id on your parent object. In my case SLASerialNumber__c is external id field.

```
Contact con = new Contact(lastName='bhardwaj');
con.Email = 'naman.bhardwaj@test.com';

Account accRef = new Account(SLASerialNumber__c='12');
con.Account = accRef;

Account acc = new Account(Name='namanTestAcc', SLASerialNumber__c='12');

Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(new SObject[] {acc, con});

for (Integer i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
    if (results[i].isSuccess()) {
        System.debug('Successfully Created ID: '+ results[i].getId());
    } 
}
```

See the [Creating Parent and Child Records in a Single Statement Using Foreign Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm) documentation for a bit more explanation.